# Create Dynamic Through Model

Tags: django, django-models

I have many models with ManyToMany fields.

```
class Author(Model):
    name = CharField()

class Publication(Model):
    name = CharField()
    authors = ManyToManyField(Author)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
class Book(Publication):
    pass
class Article(Publication):
    pass
class Journal(Publication):
    pass

class D(Model):
    authors = ManyToManyField(Author)
class E(Model):
    authors = ManyToManyField(Author)
```

I want to add ordering field to all ManyToMany fields.

What is the best way to automatically do this?

Attempt.

```
# Substitution for ManyToMany
class AuthorField(ManyToManyField):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        class Relationship(Model):
            entity = models.ForeignKey(???????????)
            author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
            ordering = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

            class Meta:
                ordering = ('ordering',)

        kwargs['to'] = Author
        kwargs['through'] = Relationship
        super(AuthorField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way.

```
class OrderedManyToManyField(models.ManyToManyField):
    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, **kwargs):
        super(OrderedManyToManyField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name, **kwargs)
        if self.remote_field.through:
            self.remote_field.through.add_to_class('ordering', models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1))
            self.remote_field.through._meta.ordering = ('ordering', )
```